# Duplicate class error while building project

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 28


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dobbyads.dobbyads"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.7.3.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }

}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
```

adding below two implementations causes error and the project doesnt build

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model:19.0.3'


  }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requecodested.group == "com.android.support") {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "26.+"
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar 
(androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)

**Also**

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

goes red when i add those implementation

Comment: try to migrate your project to androidx. after that update your libs.I think its gonna be solved

Comment: you need to use androidx all time. new versions of libraries now supports only androidx!

Answer (score 0):

Either migrate your project to androidX, or modify the build.gradle problem causing implementation as follows.

```
implementation('com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Replace "com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2" with the implementation causing the problem.